Prove that the set of even integers is dense in $\mathbb{Z}$
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
Let X = $\mathbb{Z}$. Define a metric $d$ on $X$ by saying that if $x\neq y$ then $d(x, y) = 3^{-n}$, where
$3^{-n}$ is the greatest power of $3$ dividing $x − y$. Prove that $2\mathbb{Z}$ (the set of even integers) is dense in $X$.
I have written a proof for this but I believe I am wrong. I want to show that any odd integer is a limit point of the even integers:
"Consider any odd integer $x \in X$ and any $y \in 2\mathbb{Z}. d(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{3^n}$
It is trivial that the even integers in $\mathbb{Z}$ are also in $2\mathbb{Z}$.
We now want to show that any $x$ is a limit point of $2\mathbb{Z}$.
For any neighborhood $N_r(x), \text{there exists some } q\neq x $ such that $q \in X \text{ and } q \in 2\Z$.
Thus, $x$ is a limit point of $2\Z$ and $2\Z$ is dense in $X$. "
I don't believe that my proof above is correct. The Rudin definition of a limit point (textbook that this course uses) requires that all neighborhoods contain some q, but I set the radius greater than 1 in my proof, which makes me believe that my proof is invalid. Is there a different way to do this proof? I figured the 'correct' way to do it would be to use the metric d, since I don't believe they would provide it without a need to use it.

"I don't believe that my proof above is correct": I can see no proof in what you wrote. You only claimed that "[In] any [meaning: every] neighborhood $N_r(x), \text{there exists some } q\neq x $ such that $q \in X \text{ and } q \in 2\Bbb Z$." Please show some attempt to prove it, i.e. prove that $\forall n\in\Bbb N,(2\Bbb Z)\cap(x+3^n\Bbb Z)\ne\varnothing$.

$d(x,y)\color{red}\ne\frac{x-y}{3^n}$, and $d(x, y) = 3^{-n}$, where
$3^{\color{red}+n}$ is the greatest power of $3$ dividing $x − y$.

"but I set the radius greater than 1 in my proof, which makes me believe that my proof is invalid"  You are using the normal Euclidean metric.  The statement is very false in the Euclidean space.  You have to use the metric given.  So $N_r(x)={n\in \mathbb Z| 3^m < r$ for some $m$ where $3^m|x-y}$.

For example:   $d(582,420) =\frac 1{81}$ because $81|582-420$.  And $d(56,18)=1$ because $56-18=38$ is not divisible by $3$.  $d(8, 17)=\frac 19$ because $d|17-8$ and so on.

No, $N_r(x)$ is not "${n\in \mathbb Z| 3^m < r$ for some $m$ where $3^m\mid x-y}$".  Rather, $N_r(x)=x+3^n\Bbb Z$, where $n$ is the least integer such that $3^{-n}<r$. Now, hint to prove that $\forall n\in\Bbb N,(2\Bbb Z)\cap(x+3^n\Bbb Z)\ne\varnothing$ (which is what we want): if $x$ is odd then $x+3^n$ is even.

Heres something to get you started $N_{\frac 1{9}}(29)={k\in\mathbb Z: 9|29-k}={...,-16,-7,2,11,20,.....}$

Let $x= 2k +1$ for some fixed integer $k$. We want to show that $x$ is the limit point of a sequence of even integers $\{y_n\}$ ($n \geq 1)$ in the 3-adic topology (i.e. the topology defined by this metric). We want $x - y_n = 3^n t_n$ for each integer $n \geq 1$ (for some choice of integers $t_n$ not divisible by 3). Now since $x$ is odd, if we choose $\{t_n\}$ to be any sequence of odd integers each term of which is not divisible by 3, it will follow that $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence of even integers such that $d(x, y_n) = 3^{-n}$ for each $n \geq 1$, and thus converges to $x$.
Hence every odd integer is a limit point of a sequence of even integers w.r.t. thls metric and thus the set of even integers is dense in $\mathbf{Z}$.
In particular, one may choose the sequence $\{t_n\}$ to be the constant sequence $\{1\}$.
